# Conditional Probability - A breathalyser

Tags: probability, statistics

A breathalyser is used to check whether a driver’s blood alcohol level is over the legal
limit. 
We define these events:

$A:$ breathalyser shows driver is over the limit;

$B:$ the driver’s blood alcohol really is over the limit.

(a) Suppose
$P(A|B) = 0.9$, $P(\bar A|\bar B) = 0.99.$
A driver is stopped at random and
breathalysed. If a conviction is made on the basis of the breathalyser alone, determine
the error rate (rate of wrongful convictions)
$P(\bar B|A) = P$(driver is under the limit given that the breathalyser shows driver over the limit).

Got stuck on this one, any help/tips would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Got stuck on why you got stuck on this one, which seems to be an entirely standard application of the results in your notes, any help/tips about what is preventing you from solving it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Smoke kills :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has more than one solution.

Let us denote:

- $p_1=P(A\cap B)$
- $p_2=P(A\cap B^{\complement})$
- $p_3=P(A^{\complement}\cap B)$
- $p_4=P(A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement})$

The events mentioned above are disjoint and covering.

We have the following equalities:

- $p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4=1$
- $0.9(p_1+p_3)=p_1$ based on $P(A\mid B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$
- $0.99(p_2+p_4)=p_4$ based on $P(A^{\complement}\mid B^{\complement})P(B^{\complement})=P(A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement})$

If $p$ and $q$ are nonnegative and satisfy $10p+100q=1$ then a solution is:

- $9p=P(A\cap B)$
- $q=P(A\cap B^{\complement})$
- $p=P(A^{\complement}\cap B)$
- $99q=P(A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement})$

leading to: $$P(B^{\complement}\mid A)=\frac{q}{q+9p}$$